# Incorrect order of records from virtual table

Tags: sqlite, virtual

During testing of our implementation of `SQLite Virtual Table` mechanism we've encountered an unexpected behavior.
For the following `virtual table` structure:

```
create table X(ID int, RL real)
```

This query returns all the records in the correct descending order by RL
field.

**Query 1**:

```
select * from VTab t1 left outer join VTab t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID order by t1.RL desc;
```

**Execution plan 1**:

```
explain query plan select * from VTab t1 left outer join VTab t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID order by t1.RL desc;  

0|0|0| SCAN TABLE VTab AS t1 VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 0:D1; (~0 rows)
0|1|1| SCAN TABLE VTab AS t2 VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 4:C0=0; (~0 rows)
```

`D1` here is a value generated by our `xBestIndex` method implementation and means *descending sorting by the field #1 = RL*.
`C0=0` here means *equal operation for the field #0 = ID*.
This works as expected.

However, the next query returns rows (the alias of `RL` field is different) without any sorting.

**Query 2**:

```
select * from VTab t1 left outer join VTab t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID order by t2.RL desc
```

**Execution plan 2**:

```
explain query plan select * from VTab t1 left outer join VTab t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID order by t2.RL desc;  

0|0|0| SCAN TABLE VTab AS t1 VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 0: (~0 rows)
0|11| SCAN TABLE VTab AS t2 VIRTUAL TABLE INDEX 4:C0=0; (~0 rows)
```

As you can see there is no index mentioned to sort by.
The query executed against a real table (having the very same structure as our virtual table) looks as follows:

**Query 3**:

```
select * from Table1 t1 left outer join Table1 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID order by t2.RL desc
```

**Execution plan 3**:

```
explain query plan select * from Table1 t1 left outer join Table1t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID order by t2.RL desc;  

0|0|0| SCAN TABLE Table1 AS t1 (~1000000 rows)
0|1|0| SEARCH TABLE Table1 AS t2 USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (ID=?)
0|1|0| (~7 rows)
0|0|0| USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

As you can see there is sorting using `B-tree` there.

From our side we examined what we received in `sqlite3_index_orderby` structures (the part of `sqlite3_index_info` structure) when they had come to `xBestIndex` and they didn't contain any information about sorting.
Also the `orderByConsumed` out parameter returns False (as our output is not ordered and we presume that [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) itself will order rows).

Is this a bug in `SQLite Virtual Table` support or we missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the problem lied in improper handling of the `orderByConsumed` output flag value.

For this query with `JOIN`, our `xBestIndex` implementation returned `orderByConsumed = True` for the index that matched `ON` condition, which actually wasn't correct because no ordering was done in that case. This disregarded any further `ORDER BY` clause members.

After the fix `orderByConsumed` started return `True` only for the indexes where `nOrderBy` flag was greater than 0 and `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

As the comment in `allocateIndexInfo()` says, your virtual table gets the opportunity to implement ordering only if "the ORDER BY clause contains only columns in the current virtual table". In your query, the virtual table the sort column comes from is used only to look up the ID column, and such lookups of single values are not usable for ordering.

---

With SQLite 3.7.14, I do get "USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY" in my plan for Query 2. What are the values returned by your xBestIndex?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've found a bug in my `xBestIndex` implementation. It accidentally returned `orderByConsumed = True` for one of the indexes when no ordering required at all (for the index that matches ON condition) and SQLite engine just implied I ordered **everything** on my side.  After the fix the problem has gone.

Comment: This answer set me on a wild goose chase, that turned up the core reason for an unexpected query plan I was seeing. Thanks!